# PHP Unittest class that loads another class

Tags: php, unit-testing, mocking

I have the following situation

```
class User 
{
  private $id;
  private $roleId;
  private $role;

  public function __construct(int $id, int $roleId)
  {
    $this->id = $id;
    $this->setRoleId($roleId);
  }

  public function setRoleId(int $roleId)
  {
    $this->role = Role::load($roleId);
  }
}

class Role
{
  public function __construct($x, $y ,$z)
  {
    //...
  }

  static function load(int $id) : Role
  {
    // some magic code
    return new Role($id);
  }

  public function getRoleId() : int
  {
    return $this->role->getId();
  }

  public function getRole() : Role
  {
    return $this->role;
  }
}
```

My Problem is, how can I unittest the `User`-Class?
The Role Class loads itself from a webservice... A Stub or Mock is not suitable (I guess) because, the to-be-mocked-object is `Role` and I'm testing the `User`-Class here...

Any Idea is welcome

/BR

Philippe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case you are making your `User` class responsible for loading the role. Typically that is not the responsibility of your `User` class. Instead, you could for example define a function `setRole(Role $role)` on your `User` class that accepts either a real `Role`, or a fake/stub/mock/whatever `Role`, instead of a user ID. The retrieving of the role is then done in the function/code that actually uses the user object.

But then how to test that class?

In unit testing it is usually easier not to depend on static methods like your `Role::load` one. Instead you could have a non-static method. Then you could write a class that extends `Role`, that does something that you want it to do during your tests. Then you can also write something that checks if what you told it to do was done.

That's why it is often discouraged to use many static methods: because it's hard to test (with) them.

Answer (score 0):

Your `User` class here doesn't do anything except it loads Role. So the question is what would you unitest in this class?

Unit test purpose is to check if one method works as it should. It means if for defined inputs it returns expected results, or throw errors if inputs are not valid.

Stub or mock `Role` class is completely OK if you do unit testing. Imagine that you have next method in `User` class(pseudo code I am not so good in PHP)

```
public function getUserRights() : String[]
  {
    String[] array = new String[5];
    if ($this->role.equals('ADMIN'){

        .... some logic here ...
    }

    return array;
  }
```

If now you stub your role and in different tests you return different Role from stubbed(mocked) object you can check that your method  `getUserRights()` works properly based on different Roles.

And also it is OK to loads Role from a webservice but in that case I would call that Integration tests and in that case you want to check if your webservice works correctly and setting those kind of tests is not as easy as it is to do with unit test.

Comment: The complete `User`class is <300 lines long and does other things. This is just the minimal code to display "the problem"
How am I able to stub the Role Class from the UserTest Class? Since Role is created inside the User Class, I would have to either change the User Class to use the Mock or use some kind of DI...

Comment: OK no problem that is why I give an example of one method. I hope you understood what was my idea. I do not know how it works in PHP but I can tell you the idea and you should find a PHP framework that done something similar. Role::load($roleId) should be stubbed(mocked) and based on $roleId it should return what you define in your test. For example: `stub(Role::load(ifParam('ADMIN'))).return(new Role('ADMIN'))`